# Dynamodb global secondary index composite sort key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, composite-key, secondary-indexes, dynamodb-gsi

I'm new to dynamodb and trying to create a global secondary index for addition access patterns.

How can I create dynamoDB GSI with composite sort key?

For example: my primary table stored orders, which has these fields `User_ID`,`ID`, `Type`, `Product_name`, `Total_Value`, `Created_at`

On my primary table, the partition key is `User_ID` and sort key is `Created_at`, so I can get user's order history for the UI.
My application also needs to get all orders by `name`, filtered by `type`, sorted by `total_value` and `Created_at`
so I'm thinking of create a GSI with:

- Parition key: `Product_name`
- Sort key: `Type#Total_value#Created_at`

But when creating a new GSI I encountered this error:

> Global Secondary Index range key not specified in Attribute Definitions.Type unknown.

So what should I do to create that GSI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no automatic concatenation of values. You need to create an attribute for the GSI sort key (using any legal attribute name), construct a GSI referencing it, and put into it (via your code) the concatenated value you want there.

Comment: Ah... I see. Damn this dynamo index is so complicated. What if later on, I need another access pattern, which sort key is another composite key that doesn't exist in the previous records? I guess I need to do some data migration or add that GSI attribute to older data

Comment: Correct. It’s easiest if you think of DynamoDB like a data structure your code uses which happens to be persisted within the cloud. How does something go somewhere? You put it there. Relational databases do a lot for you. This is convenient but also a reason why they don’t scale as well.